# Html encode json values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am reading data from a json file and the titles of the key/value pairs are appearing with html entities such as ®/& etc. Although the browser should convert these on the fly but I guess the way I am reading the json document through jquery, it does not do it.

So instead of giving me symbols for these, it is actually displaying the `&reg;` etc. how do i correct this?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want them to be HTML encoded? If you're writing them to your document, then they should be HTML encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't handle them as plain text: handle them as HTML. In jQuery, that normally implies using `.html()` rather than `.text()` or `.val()`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should encode the text before you write it into the file.